# What is the time complexity of getting all the substrings of a string without a character?

Tags: string, algorithm, recursion

The objective of this is to find all the substrings of a string removing a single character.

[image: For example abc]
[image]

For example for the string abc, we need to get `[abc, ac, ab, bc, a, c, b]`.

What will be the time complexity assuming that we're using recursion for this?
I'm not asking for a solution, I'm just looking to know which is the time complexity and why.

Comment: Are all of the characters in the input string unique? Or can the input be something like `aabbbccd`?

Answer (score 0):

The complexity is the summation for *k* from *0* to *n* of binomial coefficient *(n, k)*. This is equal to *2^n*.

You can find the proof here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialSums.html

Comment: It is not a factorial algorithm? I'm a little bit confused

Comment: No, cause the binomial coefficient it's a factorial divided by a factorial, so it's not factorial.

Comment: @JacoboTapia It's factorial until you remove the duplicate substrings. In the example with `abc`, the bottom row has 6 items, but only 3 appear in the answer. With `abcd` there are 24 items on the bottom, but only 4 are needed in the answer.

Comment: @JacoboTapia After reading the question again, I think I see your point of view. A recursive solution would run in factorial time. Which is to say that it would generate a factorial number of candidate substrings.

Comment: @FedericoDomeniconi Isn't the sum `2^n`?

Comment: Maybe i didn't get the recursion part, but since you want to generate all combination of every length, the total number of combination is _2^n_. As @user3386109 said, your complexity is higher because you have duplicates.